# SQL for grouping results in same line

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have this table data structure (PostgreSQL btw, just paste some records into excel to show up):

[image]

I need to aggregate the results just like this:

[image]

My *"enter"* conditions is highway 98, miles 94 and South way or highway 55, miles 214 and East way.

My *"leave"* conditions is highway 98, North way or highway 55, miles 214 and West way and have to be entered!

My approach:

```
SELECT plate, highway FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT plate, highway FROM plates
    WHERE plate IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT plate FROM plates
            WHERE (
                rodovia = 98 AND way = 'South' AND miles = 94 OR 
                rodovia = 55 AND miles = 214 AND way = 'East'
            ) GROUP BY plate
    ) AND ( 
        highway = 98 AND way = 'North' OR highway = 55 AND miles = 214 AND way = 'West'
    ) GROUP by plate, highway
) t GROUP BY plate, highway
```

However i don't know how to group the "enter" and "leave" in the same row, don't know either if the query is correct

Anyone?

Comment: I am baffled by your results.  I do not see the relationship to the data you have provided.

Comment: yea i know, like i say i don't know how to do it

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more the logic? Your question looks interesting. I'm guessing you'll need a recursive CTE to walk the graph according to your logic.

Comment: @TheImpaler yea, i have a big table with a lot of plates that traffic on highways. I need to group this plates based on the conditions i mentioned before. The "enter" condition is when this plate entered a certain part of the highway i need, and so the "leave"

Answer (score 1):

If you create two different CTE's, one for entering and one for leaving you can easily contain your parameters for both entering and leaving the highway.  Then joining the two in the end and performing a calculation to get the period.

```
    WITH ENTER_COND AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        plate,
        MIN(time) AS enter_time,
        highway AS enter_highway
    FROM plates
    WHERE (highway = 98 AND miles = 94 AND way = 'South')
         OR (highway = 55 AND miles = 217 AND way = 'East')
    GROUP BY
        plate,
        highway
    )
,LEAVE_COND AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        plate,
        MAX(time) AS leave_time,
        highway AS leave_highway
    FROM plates
    WHERE (highway = 98 AND miles = 94 AND way = 'North')
         OR (highway = 55 AND miles = 217 AND way = 'West')
    GROUP BY
        plate,
        highway
    )
SELECT
    e.plate,
    e.enter_time,
    e.enter_highway,
    l.leave_time,
    l.leave_highway,
    (l.leave_time - e.enter_time) AS period
FROM ENTER_COND e
JOIN LEAVE_COND l
    ON e.plate = l.plate
GROUP BY
    e.plate,
    e.enter_time,
    e.enter_highway,
    l.leave_time,
    l.leave_highway
;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes helped me a lot, however focusing on "PLATE 1" on my expected results the enter for the first row and second one is the same using the query you provided. There's a way to get the next enter record?

Comment: @c0nf1ck, I saw on your criteria list that you didn't have miles in the first condition.  If it isn't supposed to be there that would change your results however, if it is supposed to have miles then a lag function would need to be added to the leave_cond cte.

So instead of MAX(time) AS leave_time, it would need to be MAX(LAG(TIME,1) OVER (PARTITION BY highway, miles, meters, way, plate ORDER BY time, highway, miles, meters, way, plate)) AS leave_time.

Comment: The lag function tells it to grab the next value in "TIME" going down.  So if you have a 1 there, that's the next line, a 2 would be the next next line.  LAG() OVER is called windowing, if you are not aware of windowing functions in sql, prepare for your mind to be blown :)

Comment: thanks for you help. Got this problem now: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls

Answer (score 0):

```
select  enter.plate, 
        enter.time enter_time, 
        enter.highway enter_highway, 
        leave.time leave_time, 
        leave.highway leave_highway, 
        DATEDIFF(SS, enter.time, leave.time) period
from    (select plate, highway, time from highway h1 where time = (select min(time) from highway h2 where h1.plate = h2.plate)) enter
        join (select plate, highway, time from highway h1 where time = (select max(time) from highway h2 where h1.plate = h2.plate)) leave on enter.plate = leave.plate
```